# Building Python 2.7.2 fails with “No rule to make target ‘Parser/printgrammar.o’”

Tags: python, makefile

I am trying to build Python 2.7.2 (the latest 2.x release) on Scientific Linux 5.5, which is a derivative of Red Hat Linux. I ran

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME && make
```

and the configure script ran fine, but once make starts I get

```
make: *** No rule to make target `Parser/printgrammar.o', needed by `Parser/pgen'.  Stop.
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Make sure you didn't accidentally turn off builtin rules, for example with the -r option to make.

Comment: Make your comment an answer. It helped me as I normally invoke make as `make -rC ...`

Comment: I had the same problem and discovered my issue was I was not running the command as root / with sudo permission

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to @Ashish Ararwal, “Make sure you didn’t accidentally turn off builtin rules, for example with the `-r` option to `make`.”